# With MultibodyPlant, why do I get `SolveQuadraticForTheSmallestPositiveRoot(): condition 'Delta > 0' failed`?

Tags: python, simulation, drake

(This is from a [Drake Slack conversation](https://drakedevelopers.slack.com/archives/C2WBPQDB7/p1590533316147100).)

I'm playing with an "exploding IIWA" demo to prototype some workflows with `MultibodyPlant` and `SceneGraph`. Basically, I'm just adding a robot arm that has articulation (revolute joints between multiple links) and dropping the robot arm from a height. When it hits a certain point, I want to pause the simulation, remove all of the joints, and the resume the simulation.

Here is the code that I am working with (which needs some Drake PRs at present to work off of a binary build):

[`multibody_plant_subgraph_test.py`](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/f6d8171fd533b2237e115c44dfda9ef84dad3414/drake_stuff/multibody_plant_prototypes/test/multibody_plant_subgraph_test.py#L323-L328)

However, when I try all of the joints and simulate, I get the following assertion from Drake's [TAMSI Solver](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.05700):

```
  File ".../common/test/multibody_plant_subgraph_test.py", line 345, in do_falling_exploding_sim
    simulator_new.AdvanceTo(2.)
SystemExit: Failure at external/drake/multibody/plant/tamsi_solver.cc:217 in SolveQuadraticForTheSmallestPositiveRoot(): condition 'Delta > 0' failed.
```

Any ideas as to why this happens?

FTR This is what the simulation looks like if I just remove the collisions and futz with the velocities:

[image: sim]

Answer (score 2):

From Sherm's answer:

> Do you have any massless or inertialess bodies in there? Those are OK as long as they are interior to a multibody tree, but not as terminal nodes. After you remove the joints all the bodies are terminal.

This ended up being the case. I just needed to make sure that I removed all massless bodies in this case, and everything worked:

[commit with relevant change](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/commit/01be6e74dc0ba88264f2f3ce1b2c50b1e105cc36)

What it looks like without doing the collision removal / velocity hacks (inertia + collisions look not so great, but it's a step in the right direction):

[image]

Comment: Good call Sherm! It looks like your collision geometry is spheres? I imagine that's the cause for the free bodies to behave like spinning tops after the collision. 
BTW, all collisions are inelastic. So you won't get pieces bouncing around.

Comment: Yup, currently using spheres: [code](https://github.com/EricCousineau-TRI/repro/blob/01be6e74dc0ba88264f2f3ce1b2c50b1e105cc36/drake_stuff/multibody_plant_prototypes/test/multibody_plant_subgraph_test.py#L165-L166). And makes sense on the inelastic part! Is elastic-ish collision at all possible with the non-hydroelastic collision model (e.g. a parameter)?

Comment: We (Joe actually) are working  on allowing this by letting you change the contact parameters. Coming up soon!